# simple_salesforce method not found

Tags: python, salesforce

So I'm using the simple_salesforce module and have been playing around with the querying examples on the [site](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce).

So if I run the following code in Spyder/Conda, I end up with the following error.

```
query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10'

sf.bulk.Account.query(query)

 'SFType' object has no attribute 'Account'
```

However, if I run it in the terminal using the IDLE interpreter it works fine and produces the desired result.

Why is this work find in one situation and not in another?

Answer (score 2):

The package that I got when running this seemed broken:

```
conda install -c conda-forge simple-salesforce
```

I uninstalled that package, cloned the simple_salesforce source code, went to its root directory, and wrote:

```
pip install .
```

Works now.